# Process Multiple Promises with Multiple steps

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want to fetch data from multiple sources.  When each data set has been retrieved I want I want to send it to another asynchronous processor like a worker thread. Then once all processes have completed aggregate the data and return it.

For example:

```
function multiplyAndSum(a1, a2){
  ret = 0;
  for(var i = 0, l = a1.length; i < l; i++){
    ret += a1[i]*a2[i];
  }
  return ret;
}

function getProcessedData(){
  var worker1 = new Worker('recordProcessor.js');
  var worker2 = new Worker('recordprocessor.js');
  var results = null;
  worker1.onmessage(event=>{
    results=(!results)?event.results:
      multiplyAndSum(event.results, results);
  });
  worker2.onmessage(event=>{
    results=(!results)?event.results:
      multiplyAndSum(event.results, results);
  });
  var ds1 = fetch('./dataSet1.json')
    .then(rep=>resp.json())
    .then(d=>worker1.postMessage({
      'set': 1,
      'data': d
    }));
  var ds2 = fetch('./dataSet2.json')
    .then(rep=>resp.json())
    .then(d=>worker2.postMessage({
      'set': 1,
      'data': d
    }));
  // Once results is populated return results
}
```

I think I need to wrap all this in another Promise But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Check out `Promise.all()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: You have four separate asynchronous operations in that function.  If you're trying to coordinate when all of them are done, we'll need to see the actual code from the `onmessage()` handlers to help you more specifically.

Comment: @jfriend00 added code to show what could happen during an on message.  Wouldn't it be 6 asynchronous processes because the workers and the resp.json() are asynchronous as well?

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve with `getProcessedData()`?  What does the caller want back from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's a different way to approach it:

```
function multiplyAndSum(a1, a2){
  let ret = 0;
  for(let i = 0, l = a1.length; i < l; i++){
    ret += a1[i]*a2[i];
  }
  return ret;
}

function getWorkerMessage(worker) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        worker.onmessage(event => {
            resolve(event);
        });
    });
}

function getProcessedData(){
    const worker1 = new Worker('recordProcessor.js');
    const worker2 = new Worker('recordprocessor.js');

    let p = Promise.all([
        getWorkerMessage(worker1),
        getWorkerMessage(worker2)
    ]).then([a1, a2] => {
        return multiplyAndSum(a1.results, a2.results);
    });

    // start off both workers by sending them their data
    fetch('./dataSet1.json')
      .then(rep=>resp.json())
      .then(d=>worker1.postMessage({'set': 1,'data': d}));
    fetch('./dataSet2.json')
      .then(rep=>resp.json())
      .then(d=>worker2.postMessage({'set': 1,'data': d}));

    return p;
}

// usage
getProcessedData().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Here's my understanding of what you're attempting to do.

1. Create two workers
2. Fetch two sets of data and pass one set of data to each worker
3. When you have the processed data from both workers, multiply the two resulting arrays together and sum the products to create a single, final value
4. The caller then wants that final value

So, my suggested code uses turns the worker message into an operation that returns a promise that resolves to the result from that work when it's done.  I then use `Promise.all()` to know when both workers are done.  At that point, you have two arrays of data which can be multiplied and summed to get the final result.

Potentially loose end: Do you have to clean up the two workers when you're done with them?

Comment: Out of curiosity, attaching `worker.onmessage` for every Promise seems like a perf bottleneck and a potential memory leak (assuming the handlers don't get cleaned up). Do you know if this a correct assumption?

Comment: @nem035 - In this code, each time `getWorkerMessage()` is called it's a new and different worker.  There's no accumulation of `onmessage` handlers here.  You will notice that I mentioned a potential loose end with the code in that the workers are never cleaned up in any way.  I didn't know what worker library you are using so had no idea exactly how they work and/or what cleanup should be done.